# I cannot add my custom control dll to windows forms application (4.5 framework) which was created by using silverlight design.

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I cannot add my custom control dll to windows forms application (4.5 framework) which was created by using silverlight design. If i'm going to add my controls means, they are unavailable & hidden(not active).

Please give me a solution..

Comment: Please edit your post to explain exactly what you want to do, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem. If you have code or research done, please include them as they'll help make it easier to follow.

Comment: I have created one control(ex: Textbox) using c#,i copy and paste that dll to my windows forms application toolbox.But it is showing like hidden(un-available) i cant drag and drop it. What is the way to resolve it

Comment: `Please give me a solution` - Don't use winforms.